# Package macros in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

Where is the best place to put a Form Macro in a Laravel 4 package? Looking through the [package documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/packages), I don't see an obvious place. Seems like it won't fit anywhere under /src. I've only been learning Laravel 4 for 2 weeks, so I'm pretty new at this.

Thanks for and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will struggle to access the Form facade if you directly autoload that file from composer.json. A better solution is to add your macros in app/macros.php and then add the following line in app/start/globals.php:

```
require app_path().'/macros.php';
```

Documented under Start Files here: http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't have an explicit place, just like on app level form macros doesn't have a dedicated file to place them in.
Just make sure you load the file where you register the macro.
You could even put it inside the ServiceProvider if there is only a single macro we are talking about.
Or autoload from composer.json.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "path/to/macros.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  If I autoload from composer.json, that macro is included in every request correct?  So would it be best to put it inside the ServiceProvider?  Right now, it is just a single Form macro.  How would I register the macro in ServiceProvider?

Comment: Yes, regular files which are not class definitions are always included with composer. With a ServiceProvider now thats really depends on the package and when do you want to include this. Just for the record, a ServiceProvider's `register()` method is called when the laravel app boots up. The `boot()` method is called when the _package is started_. This depends on the `$defer` param. If the provider is deferred it will only run `boot()` when the registered handle in the IoC container is first resolved. Otherwise if not deferred `boot()` is called when the provider is registered.

Comment: Inside a package it's also a good idea not to use facades, so instead of calling `Form::macro()` you should resolve it from the IoC container, inside a ServiceProvider this would look like `$this->app['form']->macro()`.